# How can I get my ZigZag code to run as a multiple "Zig" and then a "Zag" consecutively? instead of multiple "Zig"s and then multiple "Zag"s

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

The question I am working on is "Write a function that receives a turtle and a positive integer . The function uses the turtle to draw a zigzag shape like in the figure, with  peaks." So my end result should be "ZigZag(turtles,n)" function, if I put n=5 then I should get a zigzag pattern that has 5 peaks and 4 minimums and turtle back in the same starting position.

This is what my Code looks like right now on TurtleWorld. When I run the program, the turtle makes 2 Zigs and then 1 Zag instead of alternating functions. Have to stay within very basic programs.

```
from TurtleWorld import *

world = TurtleWorld()
franklin = Turtle()

def zig(turtle,n):
    for i in range(n):
        fd(turtle,25)
        rt(turtle,90)
        fd(turtle,25)
def zag(turtle,n):
    for i in range(n):
        fd(turtle,25)
        lt(turtle,90)
        fd(turtle,25)
def zigzag(turtle,n):
    lt(turtle,45)
    for i in range(n):
        zig(turtle,n)
        zag(turtle,n-1)   
zigzag(franklin,2)
```

Comment: `zigzag(franklin,2)` should be `zigzag(franklin,5)` to match the description, right? What's your rationale behind the `n-1` in `zag(turtle,n-1)`? Why do `zig` and `zag` need counts--it seems they could do one zig or zag?

Answer (score 0):

In your `zig`/`zag` functions, you have them each do `n` iterations,
and in your `zigzag` function,
you call `zig` `n` times (in this case 2) and `zag` `n - 1` (in this case 1) times.
If you want `zig` and `zag` to alternate,
and for `zag` to be called one less time than `zig`,
you should remove the for loop from you `zig`/`zag` functions:

```py
def zig(turtle):
    fd(turtle, 25)
    rt(turtle, 90)
    fd(turtle, 25)

def zag(turtle):
    fd(turtle, 25)
    lt(turtle, 90)
    fd(turtle, 25)
```

In `zigzag`, you should keep the for loop but instead do:

```py
def zigzag(turtle, n):
    lt(turtle, 45)

    for i in range(n):
        zig(turtle)

        if i != n - 1:
            zag(turtle)
```

this runs `zig`, and if it isn't the last iteration, also runs `zag`.